# Merge submodule while there is a folder by the same name in branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-submodules, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

[image]

Here M means Master, MS means Master with submodule and FB means a FooBranch.

The FooBranch has been created from master at point Mb. At point MSd, a sub-directory named FooDir in master has been changed into a submodule. Now, master should be merged into FooBranch, with that submodule. We are in MSe and FBd points of master and FooBranch, respectively. FooDir is exist in both branches, in master it is a submodule, but it is just a subdirectory in FooBranch. From now on it should be also a submodule in FooBranch like in master.

```
$ git status
On branch master
”Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'”

$ git checkout FooBranch
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    FooDir/blablabla
Aborting

$ git checkout -f FooBranch
warning: unable to rmdir 'FooDir': Directory not empty
Checking out files: 100% (2315/2315), done.
Branch 'FooBranch' set up to track remote branch 'FooBranch' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'FooBranch'

$ git merge master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

$ git merge master --allow-unrelated-histories
Loads of CONFLICTS

$ git rebase master
...
Adding FooDir/abc.txt
error: refusing to lose untracked file at 'FooDir/abc.txt'
CONFLICT (file/directory): There is a directory with name FooDir in First snapshot of the ... Adding FooDir as FooDir~HEAD
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 First snapshot of the X interface.
```

All the changes in FooBranch is independent from master branch. The FooDir directory in FooBranch should be changed into a submodule and should be a copy-paste of master branch.

How can I do this merge.

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   FooDir (modified content)
```

I tried also `$ git checkout master FooDir` and 
`$ git submodule update --init`. it was not helpful!

```
$ cat .git/config 
[submodule "FooDir"]
    active = true
    url = git@bitbucket.org:path/FooDir.git
```

Comment: Are there changes in FooDir, on the FooBranch, that you want to keep?

Comment: No, all the contents of FooDir should be updated with the master submodule. I tried also $ git checkout master FooDir . it was not helpful!

Answer (score 0):

these commands solved the issue:

```
$ git checkout FooBranch -f
$ git checkout master FooDir
$ cd FooDir/
$ git reset --hard HEAD
$ git clean -fdx
$ git pull
```